# Excel 2003 upgrading to Excel 2010, will it break our models?

Tags: microsoft-excel, upgrade, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-excel-2010

My office is upgrading from Excel 2003 to Excel 2010 and we have a lot of tools in Excel 2003 (complex custom formulas, named ranges, VBA, pivots... almost every feature of excel can be found in at least one of our tools).

What kind of problems could crop up? A lot of the stuff I've tried have worked perfectly, but I've heard that some VBA will no longer work and was wondering if there was a list somewhere of which VBA commands might cause problems after transitioning to 2010.  I've been told that excel 2007 and excel 2010 are very compatible with each other, but the problem is a few of the excel 2003 things didn't make it to excel 2007 and thus not 2010, so a list of VBA that no longer works in 2007 might be just as helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start would be the compatibility documents from Microsoft, including:

[Convert a workbook to the Excel 2010 file format](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-office-excel-2010-with-earlier-versions-of-excel-HA010342994.aspx#BM4) and [Excel 2007 and Excel 97-2003 features that are not supported in Excel 2010](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-office-excel-2010-with-earlier-versions-of-excel-HA010342994.aspx#BM5), both part of the larger [Use Office Excel 2010 with earlier versions of Excel](http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-office-excel-2010-with-earlier-versions-of-excel-HA010342994.aspx) document.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can answer this is to to do testing. Upgrade one of your development machines to Excel 2010 and try for yourself.

Microsoft Technet has an article about the changes:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179167.aspx

Comment: Our testing machine is going to be set up soon with Excel 2007 (and not excel 2010) and we'll have a little time to test on that before we all get upgraded to 2010.  After which if we still need 2003, we have a testing machine for that too in case some things are still not working in the newer version.  I just want to get as much information as possible while I am waiting for the test machine, since we don't get very much time to test.

Comment: Without passing judgement on your process, it saddens me to hear that your testing window is so small.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with migration in regards to Pivot Tables.

[One Example](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excelchart/thread/1e381eac-3c7a-4068-bc5e-e63fe26dce88) (there are more problems than just this).

My company is upgrading next year, and I plan on allocating a few weeks to fix all the spreadsheet upgrade bugs that come out.